# Find a basis S in $R^{4}$ such that $M_{S}(F)$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization

[image]

$F(x,y,z,t) = (5x+6y+3z-6t, 2y, -6x-6y-4z+6t, 3y-t)$. Find a basis $S$ in $R^{4}$ such that that $M_{S}(F)$ is diagonal. Find also the matrix itself.

I have never met task like this one and I don't really don't know what should be my first step.

I tried to find a basis for $(5x+6y+3z-6t, 2y, -6x-6y-4z+6t, 3y-t)$ and I got an identity matrix. However I don't really fell if this step even helped something.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply find a basis of eigenvectors of this endomorphism. That's all.

Comment: I know how to find eigenvectors when I am given some specified matrix. In that case I am "blind".

Comment: Take$$\begin{pmatrix}5&6&3&-6\\0&2&0&0\\-6&-6&-4&6\\0&0&3&-1\end{pmatrix},$$which is the matrix of $F$ with respect to the canonical basis.

Comment: Right. We can use the canonical one. Thanks

Comment: "find a basis of eigenvectors" can you shortly explain why we do that in this case? Coz I am not sure why we do that. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesSmith Because if you find such a basis $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and if, for each $j$, $F(v_j)=\lambda_jv_j$, then $M_S(F)$ will be a diagonal matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal will be the $\lambda_j$'s.